# web3.isConnected is not a function

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am a new！

code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
web3.isConnected()
```

[image]

[image]

why the error is `web3.isConnected is not a function`?
thx!

Answer (score 13):

Your problem is caused by the Web3 version your are currently using. I guess it is `1.0.0-beta.18`

In *package.json*, you must have

```
"dependencies": {
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.18"
}
```

**Solution 1: Downgrade to a stable version**

I recommend to downgrade to the latest stable  version `0.19.0`

i Edit *package.json*

ii Change the version of web3

```
"dependencies": {
    "web3": "0.19.0"
}
```

**Solution 2: Keep using the beta**

First of all, the documentation is [here](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/).

I think (not 100% sure), this code should do the job to check if the client is connected or not to the node:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
var web3 = new Web3(provider);

console.log("isConnected=");
web3.eth.net.isListening().then(console.log);
```

You might need to install **web3-net**: `npm install --save web3-net`

Comment: yes，i use "1.0.0-beta.18",thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are using pre-1.0 version of web3 from a place where the provider object does not have the method `isConnected()` defined.

From the picture above, I've guessing this is ganache-cli or `truffle develop`, formerly testrpc.  I guess these clients have a custom provider because both `HttpProvider` and `IpcProvider` do have these functions defined.

Apparently this method has been deprecated/removed from web3.js in 1.0.

Pre 1.0 docs:  https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3isconnected

Missing from 1.0-beta docs:  http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html

Comment: so any idea what the new method to check a connection is? they just removed this critical startup function without any re-direction or "deprecated use XXX". nice job.